# Extracting Monthname and Year from a string

Tags: php, mysql, dayofmonth

I have to extract the month name and year from the string of the form mmm-yy (Eg. Jan-20) using mysql query. I have tried the following query it returns only NULL. The query is:

```
SELECT monthname(mon)FROM month_extract_plan

Sample data: 

Jan-20
Feb-20
Dec-19
```

Comment: any chance that you can add sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Query like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, '-', 1)  as MyMonth,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, '-', -1) as MyYear
FROM month_extract_plan;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
STR_TO:Date

```
SELECT monthname(STR_TO_DATE('Jan-20','%b-%y')) ,YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('Jan-20','%b-%y'))
```

gets you

> 'January  2020

Comment: Thank You so much ... I need to get year also

Comment: You get a date there you can use every date function of mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date